# How to filter Category Post to month and year

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm new to wordpress and trying to add a Year and Month Filter. I have added  the HTML content via DIVI Code Block on the category page

```
<select name="year_filter" id="ytr">
<option value="">Select Year</option>
<option value="2017">2017</option>
<option value="2018">2018</option>
<option value="2019">2019</option>

</select>
<select name="date_filter" id="dtr">
<option value="">Select Month</option>
<option value="01">January</option>
<option value="02">February</option>
<option value="03">March</option>
<option value="04">April</option>
<option value="05">May</option>
<option value="06">June</option>
<option value="07">July</option>
<option value="08">August</option>
<option value="09">September</option>
<option value="10">October</option>
<option value="11">November</option>
<option value="12">December</option>
</select>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){

 $('#dtr').change(function() {

 window.location.href = "/bulletin/?month_filter="+$(this).val();

 });
$('#ytr').change(function() {

 window.location.href = "/bulletin/?year_filter="+$(this).val();

 });
 });
</script>
```

Here is the logic till now i have come to so far

```
function date_filter_where($where = '') {
      if( isset($_GET['year_filter']) && $_GET['year_filter'] != '')
      {
            $filtered_date_filter_from = sanitize_text_field( $_GET['year_filter'].'-01-01', false );
            $filtered_date_filter_to = sanitize_text_field( $_GET['year_filter'].'-12-31', false );
    $where .= " AND post_date >= '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime($filtered_date_filter_from)). " 00:00:00' AND post_date <= '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime($filtered_date_filter_to)) . " 23:59:59'";
      }
    if( isset($_GET['month_filter']) && $_GET['month_filter'] != '')
    {
        $filtered_date_filter_from = sanitize_text_field( date('Y').'-'.$_GET['month_filter'].'-01', false );
        $filtered_date_filter_to = sanitize_text_field( date('Y').'-'.$_GET['month_filter'].'-31', false );
        $where .= " AND post_date >= '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime($filtered_date_filter_from)). " 00:00:00' AND post_date <= '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime($filtered_date_filter_to)) . " 23:59:59'";
    }

    return $where;
  }
```

I'm not sure if above Php code will work or not. If it is correct, where should i add this above function to apply a specific category page named bulletins

Comment: That code would go in your functions.php file.

Comment: How to call this function?